# how thread is implemented in c++

Tags: c++, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define NOPER 4

struct operation
{
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int op;
    double result;
};

void *calculator(void *pos_void_ptr)
{
    struct operation *pos_ptr = (struct operation *)pos_void_ptr;
    switch(pos_ptr->op)
    {
        case 0: pos_ptr->result = pos_ptr->val1 + pos_ptr->val2; 
                break;
        case 1: pos_ptr->result = pos_ptr->val1 - pos_ptr->val2; 
                break;
        case 2: pos_ptr->result = pos_ptr->val1 * pos_ptr->val2; 
                break;
        case 3: if (pos_ptr->val2 != 0)
                    pos_ptr->result = (double) pos_ptr->val1 / pos_ptr->val2; 
                else
                    pos_ptr->result = 0;         
                break;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    static struct operation operations[NOPER];
    pthread_t tid[NOPER];

    for(int i=0;i<NOPER;i++)
    {
        operations[i].op = i;
        std::cin >> operations[i].val1;
        std::cin >> operations[i].val2;
        if(pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, calculator, &operations[i])) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;

        }       
    }
    // Wait for the other threads to finish.
    for (int i = 0; i < NOPER; i++)
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < NOPER; i++)
    {
        switch(operations[i].op)
        {
            case 0: std::cout << operations[i].val1 << " + " << operations[i].val2 << " = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << operations[i].result << std::endl;
                    break;
            case 1: std::cout << operations[i].val1 << " - " << operations[i].val2 << " = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << operations[i].result << std::endl;
                    break;
            case 2: std::cout << operations[i].val1 << " * " << operations[i].val2 << " = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << operations[i].result << std::endl;
                    break;
            case 3: std::cout << operations[i].val1 << " / " << operations[i].val2 << " = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << operations[i].result << std::endl;
                    break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to have the basic idea about what goes inside the

```
void *calculator(void *pos_void_ptr)
    {
        struct operation *pos_ptr = (struct operation *)pos_void_ptr;
        switch(pos_ptr->op)
```

and what are these parameters in the

`(pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, calculator, &operations[i])`

and how to implement this in any program? this program takes 2 inputs 4 times and it add the first 2 elements then multiply the second 2 elements then subtract the third 2 elements then divide the fourth 2 elements

Comment: The functional implementation you ask about in your body is unrelated to concept, use and implementation of threads. You will have to clarify what you want to know.

Comment: In C++ I'd suggest using `std::thread` rather than pthreads.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: Did you read the pthread documentation about the function? Which parameter there isn’t explained clearly? Do note this isn’t C++ threading, this is pthread, which is completely different library.

Answer (score 0):

Here you define 4 thread identifiers that you'll later pass to `pthread_create`:

```
pthread_t tid[NOPER];
```

Then you create 4 threads:

```
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, calculator, &operations[i])
```

First argument is the `pthread_t` identifier, second one is an optional attribute parameter of type `pthread_attr_t` that can be initialized with `pthread_attr_init` function, third one is the name of the function that the new thread will execute, and fourth one is the parameter(s) for the function passed as 3rd argument.

In the `calculator` function you basically cast a void pointer parameter to an `operation` struct and switch on its `op` field to determine whether to add, subtract, multiply, or divide.